# Flood records/database in Europe

Tags: data, web, europe, flood

Anyone knows where I can find a complete* database with the historic flood occurrence in Europe, at least since the 70's ?

I am looking for some information on the date, number of floods**, amount precipitation**, as well as the location*** (the region and/or the affected city will be nice).

*complete in time(from the 70's  or 80's until now)
**both informations are not extremely important
***a name will be enough

I am not looking for a database with the geographic coordinates of the flood extent, just a reference for the name of the region/city

Comment: I could imagine that no such database exists yet. Your best chance is asking the individual meteorological and geologic surveys or water ministries.

Comment: look at [European Union floods portal](http://floods.jrc.ec.europa.eu/)

Comment: country by country, I know the Environment Agency has this in England and Wales but they will not release the GIS data for it. Example http://maps.environment-agency.gov.uk/wiyby/wiybyController?x=531500.0&y=181500.0&topic=floodmap&ep=map&scale=9&location=London,%20City%20of%20London&lang=_e&layerGroups=default&distance=&textonly=off#x=533103&y=180024&lg=1,&scale=8 (years ago ononemap got in trouble for scraping data from EA servers without permission).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R. 70 and 80 will be difficult, Weather/ Preciptation data only:

There first address for preciptation data is European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts in Reading.

http://www.ecmwf.int/

There are  bunch of data products mostly free for download.  Look for the data center, reanalysis projects adressing the 60s and 80s.

There is a project called GHCN Global Historical Climatology Network at NOAA and alot of world wide preciptation products are available there

http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/land-based-station-data/land-based-datasets/global-historical-climatology-network-ghcn

There is an other database at NOAA called GCPC 
Version 2.2 Combined Precipitation Data Set 2.5x2.5 degrees resolution 
but from 1979 till 2013 I' think monthly means
http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/gridded/data.gpcp.html

From the Swedish Baltic NEST Institute you can get runoff and weather data - a surroagte called BED -  Baltic Environmental Database (the runoff basin of the baltic sea covers "the half" of europe)
http://nest.su.se/bed/

The spanish provider ogimet.com has a hourly database of synop/metar weather telegrams from europe (or the world?) from the 2000 (synop) till now, with a very dense station net ( boys, stations, ships, oil/heli platforms, airports) ..but very heterogenous ..alot of work

http://www.ogimet.com/synops.phtml.en

If you are interested, I can give you a harvester/decoder running in Perl on LINUX/ Postgresql.